# Create an image from raw pixels, but color is not able to displayed according byRGBA hex value

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgimage, bitmapdata

```
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)


    let bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, 192, 192, 8, 0, colorSpace,bitmapInfo.rawValue)

    let bitmapData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>(CGBitmapContextGetData(bitmap))
    var j = 0
    for var i = 0; i < 192; i++ {
        for j = 0; j < 192; j = j + 16 {
            for var k = 0; k < 16; k++ {

                let offset = matrix.rows * i + j + k
                if(k < 4){
                    bitmapData[offset] = 0xff0000ff  //red
                }
                else{
                    bitmapData[offset] = 0xffff00ff  //yellow
                }
            }
        }
    }

    let imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap)
    let image = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef!)
```

Above is my code for create an image from raw pixels. I set color is 0xff0000ff and 0xffff00ff. However, when the image displayed in the UIimageview, it display some random color or is not able to display color.

For example, currenctly the color are 0xffff00ff and  0xff0000ff, but what my app displayed like this:

[image]

Does anybody know how to set up color to bitmap?

Comment: you probably just need to try ARGB instead of RGBA. put your alpha before red, green and blue values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see red and magenta in your output. You say you used color values `0xffff00ff` and `0xff0000ff`. Therefore I deduce that the byte order in your bitmap is ABGR.

If you change your bitmapInfo to `CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue`, you'll get the byte order you expect.

Comment: can you explain whats the difference between  "CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue" and "CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue"

Comment: One puts the bytes in RGBA odrer, and the other puts them in ABGR order.

Comment: but i tried if I delete CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big.rawValue this condition, the result is not able to display, why?

Comment: I don't understand that question.

Comment: What I meant is that if I wrote like this "CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue) " without "CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue", the result is not able to display image or wrong color of image. So what is the functionality of "CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue"?

Comment: Apparently the function is to create a bitmap that you can use. I don't know the exact effects of omitting a byte order flag.